# Циклический сдвиг массива, рекуррентные соотношения

Tags: алгоритм, рекурсия, любой-язык

Суть задачи заключается в следующем.

Входной файл имеет следующий вид:

**Например:**

> **Входной файл**
>    10
>   aaaaaaaaab
>   aaaaaaaaba
>
> **Выходной файл**
>   1

Во входном файле 3 строчки. В первой строке записано единственное число

```
  n (1 ≤ n ≤ 1 000 000).
```

Далее следуют две строки длиной n, состоящие исключительно из маленьких букв латинского алфавита.
**Необходимо проверить, возможно ли привести первую строку ко второй путем циклического сдвига влево.** В примере выше, это возможно. Понадобится циклически сдвинуть влево первую строку на 1 элемент. В выходной файл мы записываем кол-во элементов, которые понадобилось сдвинуть для получения результата. В данном примере в выходном файле будет 1. Если получить желаемый результат не получается, то в файл необходимо записать -1.

**Ограничение есть только на время** (3 секунды максимум), на память никаких ограничений нет.

Что я смог придумать: сдвигать на 1 элемент по циклу и проверять, получили ли мы правильный результат (сдвиг я осуществлял при помощи реверса строки). Алгоритм не оптимальный, проверку по времени не проходит.

**Эта задача относится к теме рекуррентных соотношений**, но я не догадался как их тут использовать. Помогите с алгоритмом, пожалуйста.

Вот еще примеры:

> **Входной файл**
>   10
>   aaaaaaaaab
>   aaaaaaabaa
>
> **Выходной файл**
>   2

////////////////////////////////////////////

> **Входной файл**
>   7
>   aabaabc
>   baabaaa
>
> **Выходной файл**
>   -1

Comment: URL не дадите? проверить пару идей...

Comment: Тут вроде есть эта задача: http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1423

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно подсчитать [автокорреляционную функцию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) последовательности. Далее одним пробегом найти, при какой величине сдвига автокорреляционная функция принимает значение, равное сумме квадратов чисел последовательности (помним, что char имеет численное представление, не забываем буквы преобразовать к int, чтобы не переполниться).

Если хотя бы в одной точке автокорреляционная функция принимает это значение (оно кстати будет максимумом этой функции), то одна последовательность является циклическим сдвигом другой, и величина необходимого сдвига как раз и будет тем k, в котором автокорреляция максимальна.

Прикинем сложность алгоритма. Автокорреляцию можно подсчитать с помощью быстрого [дискретного преобразования Фурье](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B5) (переворачиваем вторую последовательность, и затем считаем свёртку). Это займёт O(nlogn), затем один пробег: O(n), итого O(nlogn).

Второй вариант. Берём вторую строку s2, приписываем её саму к себе s2+s2, затем делаем поиск строки s1 в строке s2+s2, это можно сделать [алгоритмом Кнута-Морриса-Пратта](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9A%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B0) за O(n) (подсчётом [префикс-функции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), или подсчётом [Z-функции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)), если найдётся вхождение, то ответ "да", и индекс вхождения это величина искомого циклического сдвига. Итоговая сложность O(n), думаю этот алгоритм асимптотически оптимален.

Далее реализация на c++. Если хотите подумать самостоятельно - не читайте код. Сделано всё, за исключением, возможно, мелких ошибок типа ввода/вывода (функции поиска точно протестированы, остальное не тестил).

Реализация асимптотики O(n), реализацию через преобразование Фурье лень делать, она сложнее и там кода больше :)

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
std::vector<int> z_function(const T& str)
{
    int n = str.size();
    std::vector<int> answer(n, 0);
    int l, r;
    l = 0;
    r = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (i < r)
        {
            answer[i] = std::min(r - i, answer[i - l]);
        }
        while ( ( i + answer[i] < n ) && ( str[answer[i]] == str[i + answer[i]]) )
        {
            ++answer[i];
        }
        if ( i + answer[i] > r)
        {
            l = i;
            r = i + answer[i];
        }
    }
    return answer;
}

template<class T>
std::vector<int> search_kmp(const T& pattern, const T& text, const T& marker = T("#"))
{
    std::vector<int> zf = z_function(pattern + marker + text);
    int ps = pattern.size();
    int ts = text.size();
    std::vector<int> answer;
    answer.reserve(ts);
    for (int i = 0; i + ps - 1 < text.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (zf[i + ps + 1] == ps)
        {
            answer.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    return answer;
}

int main()
{
    int N;
    std::string str1, str2;
    std::cin >> N;
    std::cin >> str1;
    std::cin >> str2;
    std::string str(str2+str2);
    std::vector<int> mas = search_kmp(str1, str);
    if (!mas.empty())
    {
        std::cout << mas[0] << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << -1 << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```